# Interop with Java System Tray Application

Tags: java, interop, system-tray

In Java I'm writing a System Tray application which runs in the background on a user's desktop.

How does one interact/interop with this system tray app from another Java program? I want to be able to send notifications to the service arbitrarily, eg causing it to then show a balloon message.

Any solution needs to work on Windows and Mac, and it would be nice if it worked on Linux too - but hey, Java is inherently cross-platform so this shouldn't be an issue.. right?!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the other (non-tray) programs are Java, RMI is probably the easiest approach.  If the other programs aren't Java, but have good support for SOAP, create a WSDL (including XML schema) to represent the notification message(s), and have the tray app call [`Endpoint.create`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#create%28java.lang.Object%29) to listen for SOAP messages from other programs.

Comment: RMI is certainly cleaner than my initial thought, updating a file that is watched by the system tray app - very dirty..! The other programs will be Java so I will investigate RMI. Thanks!